# Do user need to have a Power BI account to view the published report

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, bigdata

I'm developing an web application in which i have to embed a Power-BI report.So users will login into my application and will go to reports page.If i use oAuth user will be asked to login to microsoft account and will be redirected to my application again.  But what about the users who don't have microsoft/powerbi account. How can i show the reports to them(can we do this without publishing it to web where everyone can see).  Also want to pass parameters to the same report based on logged in user.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to do it? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Hi,@Ala I have discontinued the development, so no progress on that

Answer (score 0):

To view a embedded report in your web application, a viewer need not to have a Power BI account.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three ways to share your reports:

1) Publish to Web - non-licence users can access this data, but it is heavily restrictive about what type of reports you can publish and the report will be viewable to the general public, you can't limit the security - so the data best not be sensitive!

2) Give everyone reading the report a Power BI Pro Licence - users can then access any report that you give them access to

3) Put your Workspace in Premium Capacity - now when you embed the report in your app, anyone accessing the App can see it, without needing a licence, the catch here is they don't need a licence, because you are paying up front for Premium Capacity - and it is quite costly